# Is a new refrigerator likely to trip a 20 amp AFCI/GFCI circuit?

Tags: gfci, refrigerator, afci

Will a new GE Cafe refrigerator/freezer work on my kitchen AFCI/GFCI 20 amp refrigerator outlet? My current 8 year old Samsung constantly trips the circuit.

Comment: Can you *please* tell us which LEDs, if any, are turning on on the front of the breaker when it trips?

Comment: The purpose of ThreePhaseEel's question isto distinguish whether this is an AFCI trip or a GFCI trip.  They are quite different and the solutions are quite different.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you this has been an area of discussion among the electrical community for a few years. The problem being some appliances built before the insertion of AFCI requirement do not work well on those types of circuits.

Most equipment built after 2008 should be able to be installed on the new requirements and work well. You might check with the manufacturer and have them point out where in the warranty it shows that their appliance is capable to meet the newer codes.

Good luck.